# Resizing a form field in iTextSharp

Tags: itext

I am adding a checkbox field to a table cell and it expands across the whole cell. Is there a way I can control the size of the element so it does not take up the whole cell?

I [found someone else asking the same question](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PdfFormField-expands-across-entire-cell-td2145707.html) but it was from 2006 so I am hoping something is now available.

One idea I had while writing this was to nest a new table in the table cell and try do some cell alignment trickery to get the checkbox center aligned but I have already had a shower today and do not want to take another.

Edit with code:

This is the class I use for the cell event:

```
public class ChildFieldEvent : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    protected PdfWriter writer;
    protected PdfFormField parent;
    protected string checkBoxName;

    internal ChildFieldEvent(PdfWriter writer, PdfFormField parent, string CheckBoxName)
    {
        this.writer = writer;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.checkBoxName = CheckBoxName;
    }

    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] cb)
    {
        createCheckboxField(rect);
    }
    private void createCheckboxField(Rectangle rect)
    {
        RadioCheckField bt = new RadioCheckField(this.writer, rect, this.checkBoxName, "Yes");
        bt.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_SQUARE;
        bt.Checked = true;
        this.parent.AddKid(bt.CheckField);
    }
}
```

Its a bit of a work in progress so it has some inconsistencies in it right now but I think Bruno's example below of basing the checkbox's rectangle off the parent cell's rectangle makes sense. I was mainly curious if it was possible since the post I reference above made the comment that is wasn't.

Comment: Can you show the code you wrote and that results in a checkbox that expands across the whole cell. Usually a cell event gives you a set of coordinates (the dimensions of the cell) and it's up to you to use those coordinates. If you use them "as-is", the dimensions of the check box correspond with the dimensions of the cell. If you do some math, you can create a cell at whatever position and whatever dimension you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took some time to create you a small example that explains how to use cell events. See [CheckboxCell](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CheckboxCell) on the official iText site.

The idea is to implement the `PdfPCellEvent` interface the way it's done in `CheckboxCellEvent`.

In this event, you get a `Rectangle` value: `position`. You can calculate the center of this rectangle like this:

```
float x = (position.getLeft() + position.getRight()) / 2;
float y = (position.getTop() + position.getBottom()) / 2;
```

Suppose that you want to add a check box that measures 20 by 20 and that is centered inside a cell, then you'd need to create a rectangle like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x - 10, y - 10, x + 10, y + 10);
```

I assume that you don't have any problem creating a check box (if you do, please take a look at the [CheckboxCell](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/CheckboxCell) example).